# Is it more efficient to import dependencies to achieve a certain task or is coding without dependencies better?

Tags: performance, time

I understand that using open-source libraries save a lot of development time. However I was just wondering with respect to application runtime and also compile time, what option would be more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an external library you **don't have to code yourself** the solution, and :

- you're saving **time**
- with **less code**, your code base is **easier to maintain**
- the execution time is depending of the library code optimization
- if you're using maven your external library won't be compiled each time you need to compile your code